# Passing Stylesheet to View from Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is it possible to pass a Stylesheet to a view from a controller?

I have a `master.layout` file. This master layout is used for every page on the site. On the site the user can change colors and properties of their user profile, so on the profile pages I need to pass in either a custom user stylesheet, or custom style rules.

The only solution I have found is to include an `if` statement in the view and if the page is a profile page then check if `$style` is defined, if so include it. But this approach seems clunky.

Is it possible to define the layout and pass in scripts or style rules from within the controller itself?

**Edit:**

The style rules are stored in a database in columns such as `profile.background_color` and `profile.heading_color`. The controller then constructs them into either a stylesheet, and caches it, or includes the styles directly within a `<style>` tag on the profile view. I havn't decided which way to do it yet, but both are possible.

Comment: it depends on how you are storing the css. in some case, tweaking the cleint side would do. or you can pass the stylesheet as a param to the view. you need to give more info.

Comment: @itachi updated question to include the details requested.

Comment: if i were you, i would have brought all the logics out of the controller and view, and put it in a facade. the facade will search in the db for custom style rules. if found, grab it or else pass a default rule. and then another method in the facade to output it. it will keep the code clean and wont clutter either in View or Controller.

Comment: I've not heard of a Facade, will have to research this.

Answer (score 0):

The advice about Facade was weird. That doens't really help you here.

You'll want to do a few things.

In your pages controller you can add:

```
$layout->with('extra_stylesheets', ['pages/someslug.css']);
```

Then that `.css` file should be processed as PHP using a little mod_rewrite and htaccess fun so it can be cached heavily (use more .htaccess for this, Google will help).

The layout then is the only location that needs to check for extra stylesheets and your pages view has a little less logic in it and your output HTML doesn't have a bunch of nasty `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

In `master.layout`, ensure you have a `@section('userStyle')...@stop` or similar.

In your controller, set the property `protected $layout = 'master.layout';`.

Build out the css as you are currently doing and store it in a php variable `$css`.

Then you can load up the css into your layout with `$this->layout->userStyle = $css`.